# how many instance of servletContainer Object will be created in an application?

Tags: java, servlets

It sounds bit silly, but I couldn't find how many instance of ServletContainer will be created for an application? 
Is there any way that I can create a Servlet Container Object in Java inside one Servlet? , Whenever a application is loaded first Servlet is called Inside this servlet I need to get a ServletContainer Object and perform some operation.

Comment: ServletContainer object does not exist it is the container that does lifecycle management of Servlets.e.g. Tomcat

Comment: As far as i know, the ServletContainer is a "tool" of WebServer where the Servlets are deployed, it sounds weird to instatiate a ServletContainer because the WebServer is responsible for this job, and i think only one "instance" is created at server startup.

Comment: Thank you  @Rahul Yadav,@drgPP, My concern is that I need to call jersey Resources from my Servlet Class, Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: How is your application packaged? A war? Check out the docs for initializing a Jersey ServletContainer - https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.8/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html

Comment: Yes, Its packaged as War.